# Using the perturbation method to solve an initial value problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory, initial-value-problems

I am in a differential equation class and I am doing a project involving the perturbation method and this certain question is puzzling me. The question states.... 
   Calculate the first order perturbation approximation to the initial value problem.

$y''+(1+ε \cos t)y=0$, $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=0$

This is what I have done so far....

$y(t)=y_0+εy_1+ε^2 y_2+⋯$

$y''=y_0''+εy_1''+ε^{2} y_2''+⋯$

$y_0''+εy_1''+ε^2 y_2''+⋯(1+ε cost)(y_0+εy_1+ε^2 y_2+⋯)=0$

$y_0''+εy_1''+ε^2+y_2''+⋯+y_0+εy_1+ε^2 y_2+⋯+ε y_0cost+ε^2 y_1cost+ε^3 y_2  cost=0$

Then I ended up having all of the equations in which there is no $ε$, one $ε$, $ε^2$, and $ε^3$

$1→     y_0''+y_0=0$

$ε→     y_1''+y_1+y_0  cost=0$

$ε^2→     y_2''+y_2+y_1  cost=0$

$ε^3→     y_2  cost=0$

I know that I have to solve for each y, but I am unsure on how to go about it. I asked several other people and they don't know. Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Since you know the method, it is really a simple computation. What is your difficulty?

Comment: I know the name of the method but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: So first you should study the method.

Comment: Oh I have, the problem is that I have tried different ways within the method to solve it, just as the examples have shown, but I cannot seem to get an answer.

Comment: Also, how did you change the equation to a cleaner looking font in the original question?

Comment: You need to use $\TeX$ for that. For the rest, nice try, but a small hint only: write $y(t)=y_0(t)+\varepsilon y_1(t)+\cdots$.

Comment: I had originally tried using the power series, but that didn't work out. I will try to manipulate the equation so it will fit. Thank you.

Comment: I had originally tried using the power series, because that is what a previous example I had found did, after they had the equation that you had previously put up. But that didn't work . I will just try to substitute something. Thank you

Comment: If you add some of your working into the question, you'll get more useful answers.

Comment: Thank you. I just updated my work.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this earlier, you can directly reply to other comments using @David for example. Your equations look correct, (not the $\epsilon^3$ one, it should have $y_3''+y_3$ as well), The first one has solution $y_0=\cos(t)$, so at $O(\epsilon)$ you have $y_1''+y_1=\cos^2(t)$, $y_1(0)=y_1'(0)=0$, which is tricky to solve, but possible. The questions will get harder to solve as you go, as the $y_i$'s get more complicated.

Comment: Thank you very much. @David